# Runtime Exception for jars with same names

Tags: android, class, jar, package

I am developing a android application where I used two external jar files(libraries) and both the jar files have a same package name and same classes but the methods inside the classes are slightly different.

And I need both the jar files. I want to access a class in first jar but not the same class in other jar. Infact I never want the class there in the second jar.

When I try to use both jar files at a time I get exception like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/appcelerator/cloud/push/CCPushService$1;
```

So how can I access only the class there in first jar or how to avoid using the class there in second jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I access only the class there in first jar or how to avoid using the class there in second jar file.

You get rid of one of the JARs. What you want would not work in regular Java either. Having two JARs with the same classes will give you unreliable results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the second jar file.

Comment: But I need some other classes there in the second jar that is not there in first jar file.

Comment: In that case, you need to change the name of one of them.